# What is the best way to create different GUI display objects and use CardLayout to switch between them? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, cardlayout

I wanted to create a fairly simple GUI program that switches between panels depending on buttons the user clicked. I searched around and came up with CardLayout being the best suggestion.

Basically in the examples of CardLayout, you create a "card" (a JPanel) and then add each component, like buttons, etc... and switch between the cards.

What I want to create is an object that is a "card" with all the components set up already, in a separate class, and just create an instance of that in the main program. I am a beginner and do not know the best design practices, so I didn't want to create my own class that extended JPanel, which I am pretty sure is terrible design.

Comment: Does this "card" extend from `JComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it just like you would if you had create an instance of `JPanel` and add the components directly to it.

You need to ensure that the custom class extends from something `JComponent` or `JPanel` (preferably) and add them to the container like any other component, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCard();
    }

    public TestCard() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
                final JPanel cardPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);
                cardPane.add(new Card01(), "Card01");
                cardPane.add(new Card02(), "Card02");

                JToggleButton btnCard01 = new JToggleButton("#1");
                JToggleButton btnCard02 = new JToggleButton("#2");
                ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
                bg.add(btnCard01);
                bg.add(btnCard02);
                JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
                buttons.add(btnCard01);
                buttons.add(btnCard02);

                btnCard01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cardLayout.show(cardPane, "Card01");
                    }
                });
                btnCard02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cardLayout.show(cardPane, "Card02");
                    }
                });
                btnCard01.setSelected(true);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(cardPane);
                frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Card01 extends JPanel {

        public Card01() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("#1"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

    public class Card02 extends JPanel {

        public Card02() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("#2"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool, I'm pretty new to this, why do you  set btnCard01 to true, I don't see it being used and my code runs without it. Also, is it better to use an inner class or a separate class file for the "cards"?

Comment: Because `btnCard01` is a `JToggleButton` and I wanted the button to match the current screen.